# Error binding IValueConverter class in C++/CX

Tags: c++, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx

I have an exception in XAML Editor that doesn't let me correctly see my custom `IValueConverter` class applied to my view, but when I run it it works very well.

I have been reading many topics from similar situations, I found a post that is similar to my problem: [xaml Invalid Markup but still compiles/runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797930/xaml-invalid-markup-but-still-compiles-runs). It took me a while to verify my all namespaces in my solution, to finally decide to recreate the projects and build again, it compiles very well, even I can see the formatter at runtime, but I’m still facing the same issue when I try to edit my view in XAML.

If I declare the ToBrushFormatter inside the Grid.Resources and compile, I get: The text associated with this error code could not be found. Cannot create instance of type 'Promotion.DataBinding.ToBrushFormatter'.

[image: Screenshot showing problematic XAML code editor]
But If I declare it outside in Page.Resources and compile I also receive: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

In addition I have registered my *ToBrushFormatter.h* in my *pch.h*, *MainScenarioList.xaml.cpp* and *MainScenario.xaml.h*:

[image: Screenshot showing problematic XAML code editor]

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

ToBrushFormatter.h and ToBrushFormatter.cpp added.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code for the ToBrushFormatter?  Also try Build > Clean Solution > Build Solution.

Comment: I updated the post with the images of ToBrushFormatter class and header, I tried cleaning whole solution, deleting ipch, debug, generated files folders and also deleting SDF database that Visual Studio create the first time the solution is opened. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. it seems it can't find the reference completely.  Change

`MainPage.xaml.h`  or whatever page you're accessing the Converter on

```
#include "MainPage.g.h"
#include "MyConverter.h"    // include your converter.h file instead of mine
```

---

Then MainPage.xaml

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="whatever"></local:MyConverter>
</Page.Resources>
```

Should fix all your ugly looking wiggles.

---

Do a Clean Rebuild just to make sure :)

Comment: Thanks Chubosaurus, appreciate the help my friend, I did that before post the question in stackoverflow, as I commented in the post I added my converter header file to my pch.h, view.h and view.cpp files, without any success.

Comment: @RobertoCervantes I put the complete project on my OneDrive (lets see if that helps you):  https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9F2F16D176D29EFC!9920&authkey=!AAK823OSzrKtdi8&ithint=folder%2csdf

Comment: thanks man, let me check it, I'll get in touch later, in advance, it seems something wrong with my project file, currently I'm checking that!! :) appreciate it.

Comment: Finally I found the root problem, the problem start when I include the header: sqlite3.h in a class within my shared.component, then when I added the component into my Windows Phone project, the xaml piece of code where my converter is displaying show the next problem: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E). I believe I'm near to solve it. I get in touch when I find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertoCervantes I figured it had to do something with your project file.  It was the reason why I uploaded the complete example to the OneDrive, good luck.